# Do while loops stop verifying after condition isn't met anymore?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, while-loop

I have recently started learning c++ and I have a question regarding the last section I reached, the while loop one.
In this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i <= 5) {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

will the while command continue checking if i <=5 after the value goes over 5 or will it stop?
If I was making a program and changed the value of i down the line to one that meets the condition of the loop would it start again or would I have to rewrite the loop code again?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

edit: Thanks for your answers and comments. I tried putting into code what I was thinking and I noticed that changing the value of i after the loop didn't make it start again(meaning that it had already stopped checking after i surpassed 5). 
I realize it was a stupid question that I could have simply solved by trying to put it into code, but I still asked for answers just to be sure. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried? What happened? Did it meet your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed i to 0 after the loop has ended like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i <= 5) {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    i=0;

    return 0;
}
```

The loop wouldn't start again because it would just set i to 0 and then go to return 0. Once the loop is executed it won't be run again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that C++ executes the code sequentially, this means that its goes through every line, executes it, then goes to the next one. This is confusing for loops because you see previous code being executed again; therefore, to solve this dilemma, think of the loop segment as a block, once this block executes, the normal sequential execution continues.

For Future reference: C++ has a beautiful feature called Multi-threading, where you can allow several code to execute in a parallel fashion. You will meet this feature sometime in the future.